# How to capture mouse scroll wheel movement without mouse area in QML, Qt?

Tags: qt, qml

For Qt5.10,

I want to cature the mouse scroll wheel movement, and use this movement to display images to user, so the user can see one image each time according wheel moving direction!

I want the user to be able to use that even if the mouse isn't hovering the screen!

Is it possible?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-wheelevent.html might be helpful

Comment: thanks Scap, but using mouse area, make it only works if the mouse was hovering! and I wanted it to work without hovering!

Comment: @Mathiass Qt is only informed of mouse events if the OS focus is in the window, so external events like the one you want will not be notified. If you want to listen to OS events then you must use the native OS libraries.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks